# crystal report viewer working good with localhost iis, but when hosting online on myAsp get an error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019, web-hosting

[image]

This is the code that I use to load report
visual studio 2019 c#

```
public void LoadReport()
    {
        var reportParam = (dynamic)HttpContext.Current.Session["ReportParams"];
        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
        if (reportParam == null || reportParam.rptFileName == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        //string path = Server.MapPath("~") + "Report//RPT//" + reportParam.rptFileName;
        string tableName = reportParam.tableName;
        rd.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Report/RPT/ST_ISSUE.RPT"));
        var ds = dt(tableName);
        rd.SetDataSource(ds);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
    }
```

And this is my web config
crystal report for visual studio 2019 sp25

```
<configSections>
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, 
EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
requirePermission="false" />
<sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
  <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
    <section name="crystalReportViewer" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
  </sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

Comment: try moving '*.RPT' files to a folder inside Release folder

Comment: do you mean "aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319" folder in my solution

Comment: the root folder

Comment: still not working